# chrome driver doesn't proceed http URLs except localhost

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch

I'm using nightwatch.js, selenoid and chrome driver. I want browser to go to any url, that is not local e.g. `browser.url('http://google.com')`. But chrome driver doesn't proceed this request, however if I use https, everything works fine. I've tried to add flag, but it didn't work for me.

```
            desiredCapabilities: {
                networkConnectionEnabled: true,
                browserName: 'chrome',
                version: 'latest',
                ...
                acceptSslCerts: false,
                acceptInsecureCerts: true,
                args: ['--disable-web-security', '--allow-running-insecure-content', '--allow-external-pages', '--allow-http-background-page'],
                'goog:chromeOptions': {
                    args: ['--disable-web-security', '--allow-running-insecure-content', '--allow-external-pages', '--allow-http-background-page'],
                },
                chrome: {
                    args: ['--disable-web-security', '--allow-running-insecure-content', '--allow-external-pages', '--allow-http-background-page'],
                },
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have to pass all these args. I have the below config.

https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example/blob/master/nightwatch.conf.js

I am loading google and Mercury using http which works for me.

https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example/blob/master/tests/mercury.js

https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example/blob/master/tests/google.js

Hope this helps.